# Edge artifacts in frequency-domain Moving Average filter

Tags: filters, python, convolution, eeg

I am currently trying to implement in python an algorithm to identify and filter out one specific periodic EEG artifact -- the grad fMRI artifact -- as described in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4942699/), and I am incurring in what I believe to be strong edge artifacts with little to no clue on how to take care of them.

As far as my understanding, the basic idea described there is an improved version of the Average Artifact Subtraction (AAS) based on the idea of Optimised Moving-Average (OMA) that can be briefly outlined as follows.
The process finding the best artifact template is performed through iterations, and the Fourier transform of one single step of the iteration is:
$$
1 - H(z) = 1 - \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \frac{(1-z^{-M})\cdot(1-z^M)}{(1-z^{-1})\cdot(1-z)}
$$
M being the period of the artifact.

The transfer function for the filter implying J iterations of the moving average then becomes:
$$ 
H_J = 1- (1-H(z))^J
$$

Finally, in order to obtain a more refined filter, the above filter is applied in a series of J cascades leading to the final transfer function:
$$
H_L(z) = (H_J(z))^L
$$

---

The computational implementation of the filter has been approached in the frequency domain and tested on a data from a measurement of about $1.8 \cdot 10^2$ s, where my sampling frequency was of $5 \cdot 10^3$ Hz and the artifact had a period of roughly $2\cdot10^{-2}$ s.

To avoid violations of the stationarity of the signal, the original signal was high passed to make sure it has zero mean.
The time domain is then transformed into the frequency domain as follows:

```
N = len(signal)
k = np.arange(N)
z = np.exp(1j * 2 * np.pi * k / N)
```

and the signal transformed

`signal_tilde = fft(signal)`

and the result is taken to be the anti-transform of the multiplication of the transfer function with the signal (in frequency space).

`signal_filtered = ifft(H_J(z)*signal_tilde)`

Without any padding, the resulting signals ends up with a lot of edge artifact.
In order to try to avoid it, the signal was padded  with symmetric padding before starting any

`np.pad(signal, (pad_before, pad_after), mode='symmetric')`

And consequently the outcome signal has been taken to be the cropped

`signal_filtered = np.real(signal_filtered[pad_before:pad_after])`

[image: Full signal time-course before (top) and after (below) the filter]

But again the transformed+cropped signal shows unequivocal signs of strong artifacts on the edges covering approximately 3% of my whole signal. One single channel is shown in the figures below for clarity.
[image: A close up on the artifact at the left edge for the same signal]

Does anyone have any further suggestion or hints on what I could try to get rid of edge artifacts in this case?

Comment: You should post images to make sure we understand what kind of artifacts you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added something that I hope will be helpful!

Comment: The first formula looks non-causal. is it meant to for forward-backward filtering? It's also a generic moving average with a window the length of the artifact. How did you implement that in the code? Maybe there's the problem.

Comment: It is supposed to be a non-causal filter meant for forward-backward application. In the code it is implemented after calculating the z space like I quoted in the question. A snipped of the filter (filt) calculation is 
~~~
 
numer = (1 / M**2) * (1 - z**(-M)) * (1 - z**M)
denom = (1 - z**(-1)) * (1 - z)
denom[denom == 0] = 1  # fix divide by zero cases
filt = numer / denom
filt = 1 - (1 - filt) ** J
filt = filt ** L
~~~
And subsequent multiplication of my fft of the padded signal with ```filt```.

Comment: For some reason I cannot format multi line code in the comment, I hope it is somewhat readable, the exponentiation got confused with bolding but it is meant to be the barebone python translation of the formulas above